# How does webpack decide on chunk ids?

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

I'm trying to use the code splitting feature from `react-router-server`.
It uses webpack chunk ids to decide which files to preload but for some reason the order of chunk ids is different between my server and client code.

To figure out what goes wrong i'd like to know how webpack decides which chunk gets which id.